# Однородные или неоднородные сказуемые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и, егэ

На "Решу ЕГЭ" дано следующее предложение. Запятые расставлены таким образом:

**С неделю он пробирался звериными тропками и, когда вышел наконец к длинному, извилистому озеру, когда узрел на нём чету лебедей, когда на выходе синей глины у воды различил олений след, понял, что пришёл и что где-то рядом лежит место, о котором мечтал.**

Перед союзом "и" в самом начале предлагается поставить запятую, но в итоге она не ставится. Я не понимаю, с чем это связано. "Пробирался" и "понял" – неоднородные, ведь пробирался он с неделю, а понял уже когда-то потом. Общее наречие "с неделю" не может относиться ко второму слову – "понял", поэтому это просто отдельное предложение. Объясните, пожалуйста, надо ли в итоге ставить запятую перед первым союзом "и"?

Comment: Перед буквой запятые не ставят, только перед словами.

Comment: Прошу прощения за неточность в выражениях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошо, допустим, что это два простых предложения, и запятая перед И нужна. Но где тогда во второй части подлежащее? Его нету. А стало быть, *пробирался* и *понял* всё же однородные члены и запятая не нужна (у меня тоже в этом предложении конец относится, как и начало, к *стало быть*).

Answer (score 3):

Нет, запятую ставить не надо.

На сайте [multiurok.ru](https://multiurok.ru/files/ege-2023-russkii-iazyk-test-30.html) (задание **20**) тоже есть это предложение.   Ответ такой же, но объяснений нет.

Однородными могут быть сказуемые, выраженные глаголами разных видов (совершенного, несовершенного) и даже разных времен, если это не противоречит здравому смыслу и стилистически оправданно.

> Однородные члены могут иметь одинаковое или разное морфологическое выражение. [[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#34101)]

А оригинал намного больше:

*С неделю он пробирался звериными тропками и, когда вышел наконец к длинному, извилистому озеру – в незапамятные времена просевшей под грудью ледника земляной котловине, когда узрел на нем чету лебедей, когда на выходе синей глины у воды различил олений след, а за ним, чуть сбоку, осторожный кошачий – росомаший, понял, что пришел и если не здесь, то где-то рядом лежит место, о котором мечтал, которое пригрезилось в чаду голландки, в подвале насосной станции, там, далеко, давным-давно.*

Петр Алешковский, «Жизнеописание Хорька» ([ЛитМир](https://www.litmir.club/br/?b=250374&p=9)).

Comment: Красота, а не предложение, правда?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Ага, Римма. Спасибо за плюсик!

Answer (score 1):

*С неделю **он пробирался** звериными тропками **и**, **когда** вышел наконец к длинному, извилистому озеру, **когда** узрел на нём чету лебедей, **когда** на выходе синей глины у воды различил олений след, **понял**, что пришёл и что где-то рядом лежит место, о котором мечтал.*

**Решение**
Запятая перед первым **и** не нужна, так как главное предложение *С неделю он пробирался звериными тропками... **и** понял* продолжается после трех придаточных с однородным подчинением (когда вышел... когда узрел... когда различил...), которые его [главное предложение] разрывают.

**О видах сказуемых**
Вот интересный, можно сказать, классический пример с выражением "с неделю" и разными видами однородных сказуемых (запятой перед союзом **и**, конечно же, нет):
*С неделю или с две **почудит** портной и **начинает просить** молока* (А. Н. Толстой. На рыбной ловле).